# Load Local CSS File Into Xamarin IOS WebView?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios

I'm able to load a local HTML file into my `WebView` like this (this works fine):

```
var fileName = "Views/Default.html"; 
var localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
var url = new NSUrl(localHtmlUrl, false);
var request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
WebView.LoadRequest(request);
```

I'd like to reference a CSS file (also local) in my HTML file:

```
<link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The CSS file does exist inside of a `Content` folder, the build action is set to Content for said file.

How can I reference/load the CSS file in question via my html file? Possible?

**UPDATE**: Had css and html in separate folders. Put them both in a `Content` folder then updated the hrefs which solved the issue while using `LoadRequest`.

Answer (score 3):

Check this link
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_local_content/

Section Additional information

Html generated in code can also be displayed, which is useful for customizing the content. To display an Html string, use the LoadHtmlString method instead of LoadRequest. Passing the path to the Content directory helps the web view resolve relative Urls in the Html, such as links, images, CSS, etc.

```
// assumes you've placed all your files in a Content folder inside your app
string contentDirectoryPath = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "Content/");
string html = "<html><a href='Home.html'>Click me</a></html>";
webView.LoadHtmlString(html, new NSUrl(contentDirectoryPath, true));
```

Comment: Correct answer, but better if you copy-paste the code here in case the link becomes broken in the future

Comment: I've seen this, but `LoadHtmlString` takes a string. Do I have to read *all* my html files as a string just for the that method? Honestly, seems like I am missing something.

Comment: I think you can load only one html at once. So I don't see a big problem to read it before you set source of webview